# Receive data from PostBack in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm using jQuery to make postback then in my `.ascx` file I have code like this:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
        var dataItems = args.get_dataItems();
        alert(dataItems['ctl00_cphContent_articleList_tbUpdate']);
    }
}
```

Where on the Internet can I find specification of `args` object? What methods has it got?

Second, why do I have to pass in my server side data into control using ScriptManager?

Code on the server side is:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterDataItem(tbUpdate, DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

and tbUpdate is the control on the site.

Is there any more elegant way to get access to data sent back to the client side. Do I have to send this data to any control? What does it really mean that data is sent to control?
How can I consume this data from that control? I had to use [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) to find the id of the control and get access to it.

Comment: I'm not clear on your question or what you're trying to do with EndRequestHandler. How do you use jQuery to cause the postback? What data are you trying to see that gets sent via postback? Are you aware that a postback is really a form.submit() in disguise?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to do an AJAX call to the server, and use the resulting data client side to either inject into an existing control, or create new controls for the data from the server.

I can only suggest you read these articles that explain how this works in far more detail than I can go into in an answer here:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
and
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

These are the clearest and most concise documents I have found on the subject.